# Looking for neutral wire at light switch housing

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light, pool

[image]I am trying to replace a pool light switch with a SURAIELEC Wireless Light Switch and Receiver Kit.
I am from California.
Usually I see 2 or 3 wires twisted and connecting together. I see none in this box. Why? That is the reason I’m worry to cut the white wire and use as neutral.

[image: Can I cut that white wire and use as neutral?]

[Are those connections ok?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOKQl.jpg)

Comment: What region is this? Electrical codes change depending on region, and some places are just so unreliable you don't rely on the colors at all.

Comment: Assuming US, that should be neutral, but is too short to use as is.  Will need to pull out more or use pigtails.

Comment: I would suggest you look in the boxes or panels on each side of this box so you know exactly what you're dealing with. Take voltage readings at the switch because the line and load has to be accurate.

Comment: Follow the conduit  to either its source or destination and investigate what that white wire is connected to. That will tell you if it is neutral or something else.